# regex match based on number of characters?

Tags: php, regex

can regex recognize an sequence and perform actions based on it?

for example: I need regex to search for $string, then count BASED on x number of characters preceding $string and extract some data.

if anyone help me better word this question or suggest links it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `x` constant, or is it calculated from the string contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are looking for something called lookahead in regex.
For example the regex below will match only if there are 5 to 7 digits before the string
naturally - you will need to replace "string" with your own var.

```
if (eregi('[[:digit:]]{5,7}(?=string)', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PHP, but for regex engines that offer backreferences, this should do the trick (using Javascript-style RegExp creation):

```
var reg = new RegExp("^.*(.{"+x+"})"+str);
```

If x is 5, and str is "world", the regex will look something like this:

```
/^.*(.{5})world/
```

When run on this string: `somethinghelloworld`, the matched string will be `hello`.

I don't know what PHP's regex engine support, but this is a pretty common extensions of theoretical regular expressions.